# Can you unit test s3 writes?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, testing, amazon-s3, junit

Unit testing a method that verifies a particular s3 bucket exists is simple because the unit test would not change the state of s3. However, unit testing a method that writes to an s3 bucket is more problematic because it actually changes the state of s3 every time the unit test is run. For example, a method that uses `rdd.saveAsTextFile(path)`.

Can a unit test be written for a method that writes to s3 that still allows you to verify that the file got written?

Note: I thought about using a mock object, but wasn't sure how this might be implemented.

Edit: I should probably note that I am using Scala

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check out [mockito](http://site.mockito.org/).

What you'd do is create a mock of your s3 client (using `mock`), stub out the put method (with `when` and `.thenReturn`), and then verify that the s3 put was done with the right data to the right bucket and key (using `verify`).

```
val s3 = org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar.mock[AmazonS3]
when(s3.putObject(any[String], any[String], any[String]).thenReturn(new PutObjectResult)

-- execute the code under test here --

verify(s3).putObject(theExpectedBucket, theExpectedKey, theExpectedData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically when writing unit tests, it is advised as you noted that you "mock" or "stub" out any calls to external APIs. This allows you to test ONLY a given unit of work, in this case your code that writes to s3.

In your case, you would mock something like the aws sdk object used to communicate with s3 and specify what the expected return would be for calls.

http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations

Comment: In this case though, I actually want to examine the content of what got written to s3. If I mocked/stubbed it, wouldn't it just return whatever I told it to rather than showing me what actually got written to s3?

Answer (score 0):

It's not strictly a *unit* test, but I've had good luck with something like the following

```
describe ('s3', () => {
  const contents = uuid.v4()
  const key = uuid.v4()

  it('should write to s3', () => {
    const result = write(key, contents)
    assertSuccess(result)
  }

  it('should read from s3', () => {
    const result = read(key)
    assertSuccess(read, contents)
  }

  it('should clear from s3', () => {
    const result = clear(key)
    assertSuccess(result)
  }

  it('should no longer have the value', () => {
    const result = read(key)
    assertFailure(result) // or maybe assertSuccess(result, empty), depending on your requirements
  }

})
```

In my experience this has satisfied the loose requirements of unit testing (fast, reliable) without 100% satisfying the hard requirements of test independence and decoupling.

Comment: So are you saying that since the tests will be run in this prescribed order, then they will always leave s3 in the same state that they found it?

Comment: Yes, as long as all the tested code works.  If clear() isn't yet implemented, for instance, you'll wind up with something stored on s3 as the result of the test.  But since we're using uuid.v4() as the key, it will be a new thing every time and shouldn't interfere with other things.